# Rails g cucumber install - Could not find activesupport-3.1.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, bundler

I am using RoR and I am trying to use the Cucumber framework I am learning from the book "Rails 3 in Action".  However, when I type

```
rails g cucumber:install
```

I get the following error.

```
Could not find activesupport-3.1.3 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

However, when I do "bundle install", I get the following output showing activesupport-3.1.3 is installed

```
...
Using rake (0.9.2.2) 
Using multi_json (1.3.6) 
Using activesupport (3.1.3) 
Using builder (3.0.0) 
Using i18n (0.6.0) 
Using activemodel (3.1.3) 
Using erubis (2.7.0)
...
```

My Gem file can be found here [enter link description here](http://pastebin.com/bDAQbxaE) .

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `bundle exec rails ...` maybe other version of rails picks up?

also env variable `BUNDLE_GEMFILE` is set to other Gemfile?